# php email changing the "from" address

Tags: php, email

I am trying to send automated emails with a clean "From" address.  When it sends the email its using the name I want with @my-website.com attached right after, how do I get rid of it?

Example

```
  $address = "user@example.com";
    $subject = "Confirmation";
    $msg = "Registered";
    $headers = "From: MyWebsite \r\n";

    mail($address, $subject, $msg, $headers);
```

The result I get in my inbox when I test it is, MyWebsite@my-website.com instead of just MyWebsite

Answer (score 1):

I think

```
$headers = "From: MyWebsite <MyWebsite@my-website.com> \r\n";
```

would do

If not, try reading http://www.sitepoint.com/advanced-email-php/

Answer (score 0):

It's working correctly. You need the complete domain with `mail()` it's required for the `mail()` function to parse and legally under the `CAN-SPAM` act.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$headers = "From: MyWebsite <MyWebsite@my-website.com> \r\n";
```

This will show the name "MyWebsite" in most email clients, and also includes your email address. (Valid email should have a real From: email address.)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the from address to the string (including the quotes):

```
"MyWebsite" <whatever@my-website.com>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't specify `MyWebsite` as sender because it's not a valid email address. You could try the following code:

```
$headers = "From: MyWebsite <whatever@my-website.com> \r\n";
```